# How to access Image sequence in a HEIC file ( using C#)?

Tags: c#, wic, heif, heic

I want to access Image sequence contained in a Heic Container using C#.

In windows 10, the [HEIF Image Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/heif-image-extensions/9pmmsr1cgpwg?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) enables reading (HEIF) files. It is supposed to be extended to [WIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wic/-wic-lh) to be used by developers if the previously mentioned extension is installed on the device.

Other libraries I found about this topic:
- [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) Can only handle a Single image in a HEIC Container.
- [HEIF-Utility-Native-DLL](https://github.com/liuziangexit/HEIF-Utility-Native-DLL) and [HEIF.NET](https://github.com/Work-Stuff/HEIF.NET) Have the same issue as the one before.
- [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif) is a C++ Library. I don't know how to use [PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke?view=vs-2019) even tho i have been trying extensively to understand how it works (I cant read C++)

How can I use my code to check if the extension is Installed?
How can I use C# to access Image sequence from a HEIC container?
And how can I do the reverce by packing Image sequences into a Heic Container?
As an alternative, how could I port this  [JavaScript](https://github.com/introvertautist/heic2jpg)  to C#, or use it with C# in a project to access Images?

Comment: As of today, my experience demonstrates the Window HEIF WIC decoder doesn't support multiple frames. The doc says there's no encoder, but it seems one is registered (CLSID_WICHeifEncoder), I've not tested it though

Comment: Okay, sorry for comment spam (and deletion): Your link for the JavaScript version was a strange silent fork -- the repo was a copy but didn't note that it was a fork. The [`gh-pages` branch of Nokia's official branch](https://github.com/nokiatech/heif/tree/gh-pages) is the right repo and has been updated more recently. It looks like it's just a descriptive website, but note the code and contents of [the Examples page](https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/examples.html).